# Extract Embedded CSV/Excel File from PDF

Tags: python, pypdf

I have been trying to Extract embedded CSV/Excel from PDF Files, I need to extract the Embedded Files from PDF and store to separate Folder, I am not getting the way to perform this activity, I tried using PyPDF2, PDFSharp, but no Success.

Here the below code i have been trying to use, Any Suggestion

```
import PyPDF2

def getAttachments(reader):
      """
      Retrieves the file attachments of the PDF as a dictionary of file names
      and the file data as a bytestring.
      :return: dictionary of filenames and bytestrings
      """
      catalog = reader.trailer["/Root"]
      fileNames = catalog['/Names']['/EmbeddedFiles']['/Names']
      attachments = {}
      for f in fileNames:
          if isinstance(f, str):
              name = f
              dataIndex = fileNames.index(f) + 1
              fDict = fileNames[dataIndex].getObject()
              fData = fDict['/EF']['/F'].getData()
              attachments[name] = fData

      return attachments


handler = open('YOURPDFPATH', 'rb')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(handler)
dictionary = getAttachments(reader)
print(dictionary)
for fName, fData in dictionary.items():
    with open(fName, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(fData)
```

Comment: does [doc](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extract-attachments.html) help?

Comment: @cards , Thanks for Suggestion, I have tried but i need to extract the CSV/EXCEL file and Save it to another path,

Comment: did the command find such attachments (csv, excel) or nothing?

Comment: Not getting at all, Have tried using Suffix as well like .CSV/.Excel but no solutions

Comment: If you know of some online (free) pdf with embedded files I will be glad to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using PyMuPDF:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import pathlib

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
for item in range(doc.embfile_count()):  # loop over the embedded files
    info = doc.embfile_info(item)  # retrieve the describing dict
    # use Unicode filename to store on disk, modify as needed
    pathlib.Path(info["ufilename"]).write_bytes(doc.embfile_get(item))
```